# given a graph G, two vertices u and v and an array A , that contains some of the vertices of G, caluclate Z contained in A(continue)

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

given a graph G, two vertices u and v, and an array A that contains some of the vertices of G, calculate Z contained in A where :

1. z belongs to Z if every path that starts from u and finishes in v don't pass through z

I have to solve it in linear time, I can't find an efficient solution

edit:
I posted a solution but I'm not sure of it

```
def algo(G: Graph, u: Node, v: Node):
    u.adjacenciesList.append(v)
    v.adjacenciesList.append(u)
    # now u and v are in the same strongly connected component
    L = Stack()
    #i'm applying Kosaraju Algorithm 
    L = dfs(G, L)
    Gt = G.traspose()
    scc = []
    scc = sccdfs(Gt, L)
    # now i finded all z in the same strongly connected component as u and v
    sccu = scc[u]
    z = []
    #discard all vertex that arent in the same scc of u and v to form z 
    for v in scc:
        if v != sccu:
            z.append(v)
    return z
```

Comment: Some clarifications may be required. In a naive interpretation, if `u` and `v` belong to the same connected component, `Z` is comprised by the set of vertices _not_ belonging to that component. If they do not, every vertex belongs to `Z`.

Comment: @user58697 Unless the vertices along a path are distinct (["by most definitions", they are, according to the first sentence in the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory))). In which case, some nodes z can be in the same connected component as u and v, yet not part of any path from u to v. That is, there is a path from u to z, and a path from z to v, and concatenating those two paths is of course a [walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path) from u to v, but it is not a path.

Comment: (1) Can you clarify whether *G* is a *directed* graph or an *undirected* graph? The comments and answer on this page all assume it's an undirected graph, but in CS and programing contexts "graph" is often used to mean "directed graph", so I'd like to be sure.

Comment: (2) How is *G* represented? (Adjacency list? Adjacency matrix? Something else?) This doesn't affect the correctness of an algorithm that operates at a higher level of abstraction, but it can massively affect its performance; so since you specify "linear time", this is an important consideration.

Comment: @ruakh G is  represented with Adjacency list, isn't specified if it is directed or not and can be ciclic i think

Comment: Is this relevant? (cc @ruakh) [https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118664/find-all-nodes-on-simple-paths-between-two-nodes-in-cyclic-directed-graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118664/find-all-nodes-on-simple-paths-between-two-nodes-in-cyclic-directed-graph)

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Good find! That answer is for directed graphs. An identical argument would apply to undirected graphs as well, *except* that the corresponding problem for undirected graphs is not NP-hard, and in fact, has a nearly-linear-time solution: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24749-4_31. So if mario has correctly relayed the problem, and the problem is solvable as written, and we slightly fudge "linear time" to "nearly linear time", then the answer to my question #1 above must be "*G* is an *undirected* graph". Whew! :-P

Comment: @ruakh so OP for a student assignment is expected to come up with a better solution than professionals have written fairly recent papers on?

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Not necessarily a *better* solution -- fudging "linear time" to "nearly linear time" seems fine to me. (The nonlinear part involves the inverse Ackermann function, which grows *incredibly* slowly -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse -- to the point that it's reasonable to consider it effectively constant.) That said, unless the OP's class has specifically been made aware of the approach in that paper, the assignment as presented seems unreasonable to me. I suspect that the OP has made some mistake in relaying it here.

Comment: @ruakh i tried to implement a solution  with all your advice, I'll have my professor check it